# Volley request always get into Error Listener

Tags: java, android, json, listview, android-fragments

JAVA CODE:-

```
 JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, "http://sikkimexpress.itstunner.com/api/homenewslist/topnews", new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            try {
                                JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("HomeNews");

                                for (int i = 0; i<jsonArray.length();i++){
                                    JSONObject homenews = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i) ;

                                    String newsId = homenews.getString("NewsId");
                                    String dateTime = homenews.getString("DateTime");
                                    String newsType = homenews.getString("NewsType");
                                    String title = homenews.getString("Title");
                                    String description = homenews.getString("Description");
                                    String mainImageURL = homenews.getString("MainImageThumbnail");

                                    System.out.println("Result:- " + newsId + " " + dateTime + " " + newsType + " " + title + " " + description + " " + mainImageURL);
                                }
                            } catch (JSONException e) {
                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }

                        }
                    },

                    new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {


                            Log.e("VOLLEY", "ERROR");
                        }
                    });


            requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

JSON:-

```
{
  "Status": 0,
  "Message": "Sucess"
  "HomeNews": [
    {
      "NewsId": 13,
      "DateTime": null,
      "NewsType": "latest",
      "Title": "Jat quota row: Haryana CM calls all-party meet as stir continues",
      "Description": "<p>Jat students block the Rohtak-Delhi road in Rohtak as part of the quota agitation. (Manoj Dhaka/HindustanTimes ). Share. Share. Share.</p>",
      "MainImageThumbnail": "http://ste.india.com/sites/default/files/2016/02/19/461939-haryana-jat-protest.jpg",
      "ReferenceURL": ""
    },
    {
      "NewsId": 15,
      "DateTime": null,
      "NewsType": "latest",
      "Title": "Sports quiz of the week",
      "Description": "<p>Which snooker player competing at the Welsh Open said: \"I get so bored at these tournaments. Maybe they should stick an adult creche here to keep us entertained because I just want to go home now.\r\n\r\n\"Today I've had a haircut, I've been in the Chinese, I've been for a coffee, I went to Bill's cafe for a couple of hours, I've had a kip, I went to Marks' and bought a bit of grub. What a day. It's certainly not glamorous.\"?</p>",
      "MainImageThumbnail": "http://news.files.bbci.co.uk/vj/live/idt-images/quizzes-sports_weekly_quiz_week7/Snooker_comp_getty_k4960.jpg",
      "ReferenceURL": ""
    },
]

}
```

I want to parse the json but always its coming to the **Response.ErrorListener**. If the status = 0 and the message is success then the value of NewsId, DateTime, title, description will be retrieve. Can anybody help, please? I take permission of Internet and I check the URL and it's working.

Comment: the url respons is XML not JSON

Comment: if you have postman then you will see the json

Comment: who told you i am not using postman?

Comment: Actually I am using postman and it is working buddy.

Comment: Yes with ARC also its json

Comment: sorry, yup in postman it's json, i think it's somekind of headers you need to send in the request to inform the server to reply with JSON, as chrome replied with XML there is a chance android also getting XML and that causes the error

Comment: @Yazan I'm pretty sure Volley passes the correct headers

Comment: Can you print the content of the volley error instead of just "ERROR"  to actually see what the problem is?

Comment: How to get the content of the volley error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am able to get correct response. If you are getting error, how about logging

```
Log.e("VOLLEY", error.getMessage());
```

One issue might be you are not using correct constructor for `JsonObjectRequest`. You should ideally use, where for you 3rd argument `jsonRequest` could be passed as null.

```
com.android.volley.toolbox.JsonObjectRequest.JsonObjectRequest(int
 method, String url, JSONObject jsonRequest, Listener<JSONObject>
 listener, ErrorListener errorListener)
```

Else everything is in workable condition.

Comment: Hey Buddy thanks a lot but I am getting **java.net.UnknownHostException**. How to resolve it?

Comment: Then you would need `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />` which you said already have, then other thing is you are not having internet connection itself. Please try opening some other website in browser, see if you are able to do that.

Comment: Now its getting right but I can't set the data in the List

Comment: Is list empty? Check it log you got the parsed json